# Distinct Record count in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a question about counting  the distinct fields that pertain to a certain record entry . I have a table called **Orders**, with two columns "OrderID" and "License Plate".

I want to return the nuimber of unique  license plate values for each order ID, 
but when I do =DCOUNT("ORDER ID","ORDERS") I get a count of all distinct records in the table, not only the distinct records pertaining to the ORDER ID.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not filtering on the id:

```
=DCount("*","ORDERS","[ORDER ID] = " & SomeOrderID & "")
```

Comment: You're not telling Access which `ORDER ID`, it's not psychic!  :-)  You haven't shared any sample data.  Do you need a count of license plates matching the `ORDER ID` or do you need a distinct count of license plates matching the `ORDER ID`.  Will one `ORDER ID` have more than 1 of the same License Plate?  If so, `DCount` won't be suitable, you'll have to query it instead.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth does that make sense? It's bedtime, I'm tired. :-)  OP needs to count _unique records_; `DCount` doesn't work that way, right?  :\

Comment: @ashleedawg OP is very unclear about what he wants exactly (no sample table, no context for his `DCount`). I only know that Gustav's answer contains a syntax error, but it might indeed also be incorrect.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks, I knew it had to be one of us that wasn't making sense.

Comment: Corrected. I think _distinct_ is used here in a wider sense - or the question wouldn't really make sense ...